# Improve JavaScript setInterval code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I currently have this bit of JavaScript which uses jQuery animate to create a water movement effect.

```
var waves = function() {
    (function() {
        var FirstWave = function() {
            this.css = function(p) {
                var s = Math.sin(p*5)
                var x = (960 * 2) - (p * 960) + 10
                var y = s * 5 + 15
                return {backgroundPosition: "-" + x + "px", bottom: "-" + y + "px"}
            } 
        };

        var tidalWave = function() {
            $("#waves-1").animate({path: new FirstWave}, 10999, "linear");
        };

        setInterval(tidalWave, 500);
    })();
};
```

`waves()` is called inside a `$(document).ready()` handler.

As you can see, the `setInterval` is set to 500 even though the animation lasts for just under 11 seconds. I did this to ensure that the animation starts on page load, since just calling `$.animate()` did not kick off the animation.

I'm sure doing it this way will have a lot of speed issues and whatever else.

Can it be improved?

Comment: You are wrapping the entire function body with an immediately invoked anonymous function expression? Why would you do that?

Comment: I have more than one animation inside `waves()`

Comment: What about `$(document).ready()` and no `setInterval` at all

Comment: @James Are you executing the `waves` function inside the ready handler?

Comment: @davin, the waves function is called inside a $(document).ready() already :) and I need the animation to keep repeating, which wouldn't happen if I removed `setInterval`

Comment: Why did someone mark it as off topic? lol

Comment: @espascarello no idea, it's completely on topic.

Comment: Sounds like it is more suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You don't need `setInterval` to keep it repeating. Add a recursive callback to the animation, so it starts itself immediately and automatically when it's finished.

Comment: @James Hm, why wouldn't just calling `animate()` outside of a timeout kick off the animation? If you call it, it should execute...

Comment: @Quentin, I didn't know about that one.

Comment: @davin, hmm that could work! I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use setTimeout instead of setInterval (there are various advantages, see here: [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)) and because you want it to repeat you should just do another setTimeout within your tidalWave function that invokes tidalWave itself again.

```
var tidalWave = function() {
   $("#waves-1").animate({path: new FirstWave}, 10999, "linear");
   setTimeout(tidalWave, 500);
};

setTimeout(tidalWave, 500);
```

Now you could also use $(document).ready instead of the initial timeout.

Comment: `setTimeout` can't re-call a function if `animate` is running right?

Comment: This seems a much cleaner way of doing things. Cheers!

Comment: setTimeout can recall the function if animate is still running. If you want call the function again after the animation has completed use the callback function animate provides you with.